# Derivative of a sum with respect to the maximum step?

Tags: derivatives, summation

I am looking to take the derivative of $\partial _n(\sum_ {j=n/2}^{n} f(n,j))$ and I am not sure how to go about doing it. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of information about how to proceed? Thanks. [Note: While I did see the answer at [What is the derivative of a summation with respect to it's upper limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248203/what-is-the-derivative-of-a-summation-with-respect-to-its-upper-limit), I get the impression from the comments the answers given are wrong.]

Comment: As written, your function is defined only for integers $n$ (perhaps even only for even integers); in that context, derivatives make no sense. If you have in mind a function that is defined for all real numbers $n$, you should be specific about what you mean.

Comment: @GregMartin: I'm not sure that's necessarily true. Consider the function $f(n,j) = nj$. The derivative of that function with respect to _n_ is $f' = j$.

Comment: True but irrelevant. What, for example, do you mean by $\sum_{j=\pi/2}^\pi f(\pi,j)$?

Comment: You can find your answer Here: 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248203/what-is-the-derivative-of-a-summation-with-respect-to-its-upper-limit