# Derivative for summation respect to the a floor function upper limit

Tags: calculus, summation

What is the derivative for the following function
$$\frac{d}{dw} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{K_o}{w} \rfloor} i^{-\gamma} \left(1-(1-w)e^{-a w}\right),\quad w \in \mathbb{R}^+ \text{ and } K_o,\gamma, \text{ and } a \text{ are positive constants}  $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

As one could see, the problem is $$U(w):=\left\lfloor\frac{K_0}{w}\right\rfloor$$ since it is not a fixed number. So, let us examine the following cases:

1. $w>K_0$. Then, we have that $\frac{K_0}{w}<1$, so $U(w)=0$ and the result is trivially $0$.
2. $K_0\geq w>\frac{K_0}{2}$. Then, we have that $1\leq\frac{K_0}{w}<2$, so $U(w)=1$ and the result is
   $$e^{-aw}+a(1-w)e^{-aw}=(1+a-w)e^{-aw}$$
3. $\frac{K_0}{2}\geq w>\frac{K_0}{3}$. Then, we have that $2\leq\frac{K_0}{w}<3$, so $U(w)=2$ and we have to differentiate:
   $$\sum_{i=1}^2i^{-\gamma}(1-(1-w)e^{-aw})=\left(1-(1-w)e^{-aw}\right)\sum_{i=1}^2i^{-\gamma}$$
   Which is:
   $$(1+a-w)e^{-aw}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^\gamma}\right)$$
4. The general case $\frac{K_0}{n}\geq w>\frac{K_0}{n+1}$ where $U(w)=n$, so the all-wanted derivative is - this is simple to calculate:
   $$(1+a-w)e^{-aw}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^\gamma}+\frac{1}{3^\gamma}+\dots+\frac{1}{n^\gamma}\right)$$

Also note that the given function may not be differentiable at the points $w_n=\frac{K_0}{n}$, for the most values of $a,K_0,\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you. According to that the derivative for a summation with respect to the an integer upper limit,  $$(\frac{d}{dn}\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(n)g(i) = \frac{d}{dn}f(n) \sum_{i=1}^{n}g(i), \quad n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}  \text{ and } f:  \mathbb{N}^{+}  \to \mathbb{R}^{+})$$. Is it correct?

Comment: How do you define differntiation on $\mathbb{N}$. Note that, in the above case $w$ is a usual real variable, it just happens that the upper limit of summation is not fixed.

Comment: sorry I mean for an integer $n$. Is the derivative is carried for the function $f(n)$ without affecting the summation over the $g(i)$ function?

Comment: Again, how is differentiation defined on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @ Βασίλης, like in the following  [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248203/what-is-the-derivative-of-a-summation-with-respect-to-its-upper-limit)

Comment: Wait, that's another thing. I'm asking what is the notion of $\frac{d}{dn}$ where $n$ is an integer. In which way do you differentiate over integers or naturals? How can you take limits? Differentiating a sum with a variable upper limit can not in general be handled as above, though.